# Is it possible to generate Multi-Prime RSA in .NET?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, pkcs#1

I have some question about implementation Multi-Prime RSA (More than 2 prime) in .NET

Is it possible to generate RSA key with Multi-Prime enabled using RSACryptoServiceProvider()?

Just reading [this article]:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET but it use a standard RSA with 2 prime.

If I want to do Multi-Prime what should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any example of multi prime RSA in C#. The main place to look is of course key pair generation, if you cannot perform multi-prime generation then you cannot use multi-prime RSA. I've checked this on Bouncy Castle as well, and I don't see any RSA-MP key pair generation parameters.

So you either have to find an external library or you have to program it yourself. Note that RSA-MP is not standardized by NIST or specified in a universally recognized standard (such as RFC, PKCS#1) so that's a pretty good reason *not* to adopt it. Many runtimes only contain  well recognized algorithms + a set of older algorithms, using NIST/FIPS as starting point.